# Unable to withdraw money from Paypal in Andorra

Tags: international, paypal, transfer, andorra

I live in Andorra. I have an Andorran Paypal account, with a linked Credit Card. The account is fully verified.

Right now Paypal only offers cashout withdraw options to USA bank accounts for Andorra Paypal users. As I do not live in the USA, I do not have such an account.

So as it stands, I cannot do anything with my money in my PayPal account, apart from spending it on goods which I have to buy online.

I really want to get this money to my personal bank account in my country.

Is there any trustworthy 3rd party service that I can send the money to, which can then wire it to me?

PS: this has been an ongoing problem for many many years.

Comment: Do you know anyone in the US that you trust (e.g., a relative)?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I presume I don't have to remind you to be extremely careful if anyone offers to help you with this, to avoid being scammed... and to remind everyone else to be extremely careful if tempted to respond to someone who poses this sort of request, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: would be easy in theory to buy bitcoin and - since you want fiat currency in a bank account - you would sell the bitcoin on an exchange like bitstamp and wire the money from there to your bank account. in practice people with bitcoin won't take paypal, because paypal doesn't have merchant protection for things that make paypal irrelevant

Comment: @johndoe999 It is in fact possible to sign up for a US Bank account from outside of the US as a non-citizen or resident. It just takes a while, and a bunch of documents. (https://www.globalfromasia.com/opening-us-bank-account/). It is also possible to set up an account with an international bank, which may or may not be present in Andorra, but they probably would have a presence in France or Spain., so if you can set up an account at a French or Spanish branch of a US or international bank, that should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to find friends who are willing to pay you to order stuff for them. Or to use it to buy gift certificates at an online vendor, and either give those as gifts or find friends who'd be willing to buy them from you.